# Probability of the first die

Tags: probability, dice

I am working on the following problem.

> If you toss two dice, what is the probability that the first dice shows a face of 6, given that the sum of both faces is an 8?

Am I wrong to assume that both rolls are independent? If not, wouldn't the probability just be the following:

$$\frac{1}{6} \approx 16.67\%$$

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are wrong, because the information that the sum is $8$ means the rolls are not independent.  In particular, the first roll cannot be $1$ (nor can the second).

Comment: I see what you are saying. Thank you for the information!